# Use a function from c++ DLL

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT and it's QLibrary to use a DLL. But I can't seem to load the function inside it and use it in my project.

```
void Compose3wnThread::GenPrinterFile()
{
    lib_3wn = new QLibrary;
    lib_3wn->setFileName(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/" + MyDLL);
    lib_3wn->load();

    if (lib->isLoaded())
    {
        typedef int (*initial)(char*, int, char*);
        initial function = (initial)lib_3wn->resolve("API_Initial");

        int result;
        result = 0;
        //result = (int)function("Nobel Superfine", 12, "D:\\final.3wn");

    }
}
```

lib_3wn is the QLibrary object that holds my DLL. And after runnning the code above, the *function* remains 0x0 or does not have any value. This is the function I need to load from the DLL.

```
int API_Initial(char *machineType, int totalLayers, char *fileName)
```

> This function is from a document that defines the functions inside the DLL I'm using. I did not create the DLL myself.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you use some tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if all the possibles dependencies of your dll are resolved and see how `API_Initial` is named (the name exposed externally) on your dll?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`QLibrary` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html#resolve):

> The symbol must be exported as a C function from the library. This means that the function must be wrapped in an `extern "C"` if the library is compiled with a C++ compiler. On Windows you must also explicitly export the function from the DLL using the `__declspec(dllexport)` compiler directive

You should add `extern "C"` to the declaration and definition of `API_Initial`:

```
extern "C" int API_Initial(char *machineType, int totalLayers, char *fileName)
```

or enclose it in an `extern "C"` block:

```
extern "C" {
    int API_Initial(char *machineType, int totalLayers, char *fileName);
}
```

C++ has function overloading, but every function in a needs a unique name for the linker to use.  To achieve this, names are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++) to encode their signature.  This means that `int foo(int)` and `int foo(double)` have different names, and the linker can distinguish them, but neither are named `foo`.  One is named `?foo@@YAHH@Z` and the other is named `?foo@@YAHN@Z` (on Windows.  Other platforms have different name mangling schemes, but the idea is the same).

This means that when `QLibrary` looks for the name `API_Initial` it can't find it.  It *could* find the name `?API_Initial@@YAHPEADH0@Z`, but there's no good platform-independent way to derive that name.

Adding `extern "C"` to a function declaration disables this name mangling, but precludes function overloading, limits the name to the global namespace, and limits the function's interface to only trivially copyable object types and pointers.

Comment: The line int API_Initial is from the document that contains the functions inside the DLL. I did not make the DLL myself. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: i think you've misunderstood the question. ;)

Comment: @RadosławCybulski The question was edited after I posted this answer to specify that the OP is not the author of the DLL in question.  Beyond that, this answer perfectly answers the question "Why can't I load the function named `API_Initial` from my DLL?" with the answer "Because your DLL contains no function named `API_Initial`".

Comment: Well no. He uses invalid name, as on windows C names are mangled with prefix '_'.

Comment: The question's title says the DLL is written in C++.  Unless the function is declared `extern "C"` its name is not `_API_Initial`, it is `?API_Initial@@YAHPEADH0@Z` (on Windows, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
initial function = (initial)lib_3wn->resolve("_API_Initial");
```

or

```
initial function = (initial)lib_3wn->resolve("_API_Initial@4");
```

or

```
initial function = (initial)lib_3wn->resolve("@API_Initial@4");
```

depending on calling convention. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. I kinda fixed it using the comment of @Antonio Dias. I used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and then I saw that the DLL I mentioned is dependent(punt not intended) on two[2] other DLL files.

The prior code is already correct.